# AJAX returning html page with JSON embedded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Im new to ajax so excuse me for any stupid mistakes. Here we go...

Im trying to code a autocomplete text box and retriving data from mysql. The code snippet below:

```
      function showRecords(str) {
        if (str.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("txtHint").style.border = "0px";
            return;
        }
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                process(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("txtHint").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "getData.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send("searchStr=" + str);
    }
```

getData.php snippet which gives back the data:

```
            blah...blah...blah.....

         header('Content-type: application/json');

         $q = trim($_REQUEST["searchStr"]);

         blah...blah...blah....getting record from database...

         if (isset($result)) {
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $listingId = $row['listingid'];
                $locality = $row['locality'];
                $data[] = array('listing' => $listingId, 'locality' => $locality);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Now this returns me the following:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>

         <html>
             <head>

             </head>
         <body>
            [{"listing":"1","locality":"Seethammadhara"},                              
             {"listing":"2","locality":"Bhogapuram"}]    </body>
         </html> (18:04:43:126)
         at index.php:92
         >
```

so far so fine, and I want to set these into the autocomplete text box, and im not sure how to do it, please help.

secondly, why is it sending me html and just not the json values array? how can i filter out the values and populate the text box?

I tried this but no luck...

```
     function process(data){
        var myValues = {};
        console.log("<---------"+data+"---->");
        $.each(data, function() {
        myValues[this.listing] = this.locality;
        });
        console.log(myValues);
  }
```

its throw out:

```
         <---------<!DOCTYPE html>

       <html>
         <head>

         </head>
         <body>
                [{"listing":"1","locality":"Seethammadhara"}, 
                {"listing":"2","locality":"Bhogapuram"}]    </body>
        </html>
         ----> (18:15:07:037)
         at index.php:105
       TypeError: '<!DOCTYPE html>

       <html>
          <head>

          </head>
          <body>
               [{"listing":"1","locality":"Seethammadhara"},                 
               {"listing":"2","locality":"Bhogapuram"}]    </body>
          </html>
         ' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating '( length - 1 ) in obj') 
         (18:15:07:058 | error, javascript)

         at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:965
         >
```

I know its compaining about type mismatch but how can I go straight to the json values to retrieve them and populate in the text box? please help. Many Thanks.

edited:

```
    function fireJson(str){
       var searchString = "locality like '%"+str+"%'";
         $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getData.php",
        data: "searchStr=" + searchString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (result) {
            var xx = $(result).filter("#listing").text();//not working
            console.log("here ->(" + xx + ")"); // empty display

         }
      });

     }
```

for some reason "post" and dataType: "json" is not working :-(
im using:code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js and code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js, but I get the thing working with the above code and get the same result as above but dont know how to retrieve the values i want. Thanks.

Edited:

Faulty html tags that caused the problem, thanks to Anthony for enlightining me !

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html>
        <head>
             <?php include("classes/Database.php"); ?>

        </head>
        <body>
             <?php
            header('Content-type: application/json');
             if(!isset($_POST['searchStr'])){
                exit;
             }   
            $q = trim($_POST["searchStr"]);
            if ($q !== "") {
               $mydb = new myDBC();
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM p_listing where ". $q;
               $result;
                try{
                   $result = $mydb->runQuery($sql);
                }catch(Exception $e){
                   // deal with it later.
                   echo $e;
              }    
              if (isset($result)) {
                $data = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                   $listingId = $row['listingid'];
                   $locality = $row['locality'];
                   $data[] = array('listing' => $listingId, 'locality' => $locality);
               }
            }
             echo json_encode($data);
             flush();

            } else {
                echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
          }
          ?>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Add `exit()` function construct after `echo json_encode($data);`.

Comment: There is too much of code for `ajax` call, if your using `jQuery` lib as well in your page, then better make a ajax call in jQuery style. **ref:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/**

Comment: Any reason you're using the native xmlhttp object rather than jQuery's `ajax` methods?

Comment: @RahilWazir: I tried flush(); and exit(); but thats not what i want to know - Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dreamweiver: I added the ajax reference above. Tried and got the same result, but wont help me achieve what I wanted. I want to get either just json array or want to know how to parse it and retrieve only the json values to populate in the drop down. Thanks.

Comment: "so far so fine" Well no, not really. If you're returning JSON that should be the only thing you're returning, it shouldn't be part of HTML. I'm not sure *why* that's occurring, but it's a server-side issue and is what's throwing off your JavaScript.

Comment: As @AnthonyGrist mentions, your output is *not* JSON, it's HTML, with a JSON-like string in the body.

Comment: @suresh Might help if you posted the entire PHP file rather than just a snippet from it.

Comment: @Anthony, I think i know whats wrong here...i got html tags in my php and thus its returning them too...got some progress but still figuring out how to parse the output and populate in the text box for autofill. For anyone who got similar problem as me just putting up the faulty getData.php above...Thanks Anthony, you kicked my stupid brain...so much so for a amataeur php man !

Answer (score 0):

I think this won't fix your problem, but some changes after your edition:

```
   function fireJson(str){
     var searchString = "locality like '%"+str+"%'";
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getData.php",
        data: {searchStr: searchString},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var xx = $(result).filter("#listing").text();
            console.log("here ->(" + xx + ")");
        }
  });

 }
```

I am not for import jQuery for doing an AJAX request. jQuery is too heavy and use it only for ajax... Personal mind :)

Comment: did you mean data: "{searchStr: "+searchString+"}" ? it isint working though.

Comment: Type was **GET**, you want to make a **POST** request. DataType was **html** you want to retrieve **json**. Your sent data would be retrieve at the url getData.php in the variable $_POST["searchStr"].

Comment: I know but post and json were not working, so had to change them and it works with get and text for some reason. I tried all sorts, may be Im doing something silly somewhere down the line...thanks anyway...

Comment: Didn't saw in your second edit. You have HTML tag in your php file which return json...

Answer (score 0):

In jquery this works for me.
I am getting the cross domain JSON data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $(".col").html(result);            

     }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/PW7fS/